# How to convert wav audio file to aac in python?

Tags: ffmpeg, wav, aac

I have a project about audio compression, I've been working with pydub I am using the function export() to write and save the file it works perfectly fine from aac to wav but doesn't the other way around it gives me this error : (From what I understood, ffmpeg doesn't support the aac format for this function )

Encoding failed. ffmpeg/avlib returned error code: 1

```
Command:['ffmpeg', '-y', '-f', 'wav', '-i', '/var/folders/n1/x3tb_rg17pdgss5jb_zr7v380000gn/T/tmp7rv9zmjx', '-f', 'm4a', '/var/folders/n1/x3tb_rg17pdgss5jb_zr7v380000gn/T/tmpco06cpgo']
```

Output from ffmpeg/avlib:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1_4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, wav, from '/var/folders/n1/x3tb_rg17pdgss5jb_zr7v380000gn/T/tmp7rv9zmjx':
  Duration: 00:00:01.82, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
[NULL @ 0x7fbbb7008200] Requested output format 'm4a' is not a suitable output format
/var/folders/n1/x3tb_rg17pdgss5jb_zr7v380000gn/T/tmpco06cpgo: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 0):

aac

```
Command:['ffmpeg', '-y', '-f', 'wav', '-i', '/var/folders/n1/x3tb_rg17pdgss5jb_zr7v380000gn/T/tmp7rv9zmjx', '-f', 'adts', '/var/folders/n1/x3tb_rg17pdgss5jb_zr7v380000gn/T/tmpco06cpgo']
```

m4a

```
Command:['ffmpeg', '-y', '-f', 'wav', '-i', '/var/folders/n1/x3tb_rg17pdgss5jb_zr7v380000gn/T/tmp7rv9zmjx', '-f', 'ipod', '/var/folders/n1/x3tb_rg17pdgss5jb_zr7v380000gn/T/tmpco06cpgo']
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't quite get your answer where do i run this command ?

Comment: @yaya49 You can run the command from any directory.